# Implementing OAuth on API with email/password for authentication

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, api-authorization

I just inherited ownership of an API (written in Python/Flask and running on AWS, with a MongoDB back end) where the only auth was a manual email/password login.

The current process is:

1. Obtain email and password from user (via app).
2. Submit to API which returns the API Key in a JSON Object once the password is verified.
3. Use API Key in all subsequent API Calls to utilise services.

This API was used as the back end to multiple Android Apps.
I now want to add OAuth to allow users to sign in/up using Google Auth, but I have hit a stumbling block with implementing this:

I can't use any other Auth such as [Firebase Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867571/integration-oauth-with-email-password-in-firebase), because even once the Auth is done on the App (Email/Password or Google), I have no way of obtaining the API Key without the manual password (because of the way its implemented).

I have gone through the following topics [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702826/oauth-authorization-vs-authentication) and on the [OAUth website](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/openid-connect/authorization-vs-authentication/) but nothing comes to mind on how to tackle this.

How do I handle this? Do I have to rewrite the API? I ask this because, if I 'trust' the OAuth module, I have to expose an endpoint and sensitive data to it (without authenticating with the API), which is a terrible idea.

Comment: Its been a few days but no answers yet. Any help??